# Unable to satisfy Bottom Constraint of UILabel to ContentView of Dynamic UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

All implementations done programmatically(No Storyboards!).

I have created **dynamic tableView** with UITableView.automaticDimension with all custom Cells. All Cells are working fine and ***this*** one too but ***this*** one is generating **Constraint warnings** in debug.

> Though, the layout is perfect and displaying as it should.

It has just one label and 3 CAShapeLayers. Below is the implementation Code:

**//BadCustomTableViewCell**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setUpViews()
    setUpConstraints()
}
let badLabel:UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
    label.text = "899"
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()
func setUpViews() {
    contentView.addSubview(badLabel)
}
func setUpConstraints() {
    badLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    badLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
    let safeMargin:CGFloat = badLabel.frame.size.width - 15
    badLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: safeMargin).isActive = true
    badLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -safeMargin).isActive = true
}
```

Everything is fine according to me, but I don't what's breaking the constraints!

The log shows this -

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282729720 V:|-(77.6667)-[UILabel:0x103179a60'65.89 %']   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x10317a150 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282729950 UILabel:0x103179a60'65.89 %'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x10317a150.bottom - 77.6667   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2827297c0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x10317a150.height == 48.6667   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282729950 UILabel:0x103179a60'65.89 %'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x10317a150.bottom - 77.6667   (active)>
```

Any Idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lower the bottom constraint

```
let con = badLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -safeMargin)  
con.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)
con.isActive = true
```

and add the setup & constraints inside

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle,reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

as

```
override func layoutSubviews()
```

is called multiple times 
 `

Comment: Your method for applying Priority worked for me within layoutSubviews but not in init() method. Also as I am using some animations inside cell with lazy variables and Async Queues so I prefer keep using layoutSubviews() only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Although it is quite late, I'm posting this answer anyway*. Most of the times, you don't need to re-setup your constraints and re-add your subviews to your super/parent view. So your `setUpViews()` and `setUpConstraints()` should be indeed inside `override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` like so:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    setUpViews()
    setUpConstraints()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Also, you don't need (most of the times, again), at least for me, to setup priorities to your constraints. As much as possible, solve the constraints issues/warnings without lowering priorities.

`badLabel.layoutIfNeeded()` isn't needed too, unless you're actually modifying some constants of your constraints or re-making your constraint. Well it makes sense to use such line if you REALLY want to setup everything in your `layoutSubviews()`

This whole class similar to your cell worked for me:

```
class BadCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setUpViews()
        setUpConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let badLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
        label.text = "899"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    func setUpViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(badLabel)
    }

    func setUpConstraints() {
        badLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        let safeMargin:CGFloat = badLabel.frame.size.width - 15
        badLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: -safeMargin).isActive = true
        badLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: safeMargin).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you have animations inside your cell? I have them, doesn't work for me even using DispatchQueue.main.async()